# Bash - until loop and counter issues

Tags: bash, counter

I am writing a script to compress video files using `ffmpeg` and trying to create an `until` loop that runs until `copression ratio` exceeds `1.5`
Here is the code:

```
 for f in "$@"; do
    BASE=${f%.*}
    filesize_compressed=$(stat --format=%s "${BASE}_${suffix}.mp4")
    filesize_original=$(stat --format=%s "${BASE}.mp4")
    filesize_compressed_mb=$(echo "scale=2; ${filesize_compressed} / 1024 / 1024" | bc)
    filesize_original_mb=$(echo "scale=2; ${filesize_original} / 1024 / 1024" | bc)
    echo -e "Compressed file size: "$(basename "${BASE}_${suffix}.mp4")" ${filesize_compressed_mb} MB"
    echo -e "Original file size: "$(basename "${BASE}.mp4")" ${filesize_original_mb} MB"
    compression_ratio=$(echo "scale=2; ${filesize_original} / ${filesize_compressed}" | bc)
    echo -e "Compression ratio: ${compression_ratio}"
    if (( $(echo "${compression_ratio} < 1.5" | bc) )); then
        until (( $(echo "${compression_ratio} > 1.49" | bc) )); do
        echo -e "Trying ffmpeg compression with CRF: "$(("${crf}"++))""
        echo -e "Deleting "${BASE}_${suffix}.mp4""
        rm -f "${BASE}_${suffix}.mp4"
        ffmpeg -i "${f}" -y -f mp4 -c:a "${ca}" -b:a "${ba}" -c:v "${cv}" -crf "$(("${crf}"++))" -preset "${preset}" -map_metadata 0 "${f%.*}_${suffix}.mp4"
    done
        fi
 done
```

Basically I am trying to:

- check original/compressed `ratio`
- if the `ratio` < `1.5`
- add "1" to the
  parameter`${crf}`(constant rate factor) and compress again
- ... keep doing this `until` the ratio exceeds `1.5`

For some reason if I run the script it adds 2 instead of 1 to CRF every iteration and the script never quits recompressing.
Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that you do `$(("${crf}"++))` twice on each iteration? I'm surprised it doesn't just fail though. To increment the variable `crf` you would do `$(( crf++ ))`

Comment: Well, one is in the echo, second one is in the actual command. I am going to delete the one from the echo and test it. Thanks!

Comment: You can drop the `if` statement; if the compression ratio is already big enough, the `until` loop simply won't be entered.

Comment: Or just use a `while` loop, e.g. `while (( $(echo "${compression_ratio} < 1.5" | bc) )); do ... done`